# Grabbing information from one page and displaying it in another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html page I'm making, which displays a bunch of category links - each of which link to an inventory page with a number of products. The client would like the page with the links to have the number of equipment available next to the title e.g.

**Excavators (5)**

The issue is, I dont have access to the back end of the inventory, its hosted with another company. At the top of each inventory it has a number of matches field, which is the information I need

[image]

Can anyone think of a way i can show that matches number on a different page dynamically (without php). The only thing I can think of at the moment is doing a really hatchet job with an iframe - but that wont be pretty or professional. Any genius thoughts would be appreciated!!

p.s the page im linking to is internal in my site - the inventorys in an iframe

Comment: Hate the job that did't have a right access on resources

Comment: So right now you have one system and have a list of category to show off and the another one is internal system that hold the entire products's information. So, what language you're working right now for server side? Or Is that only markup language(html)?

Comment: Yes the sites just in HTML - Im manually inputting the category names, and hoping to grab the snippet of information from the iframe to put next to each cateogy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data you need is an identifiable container, and you can work out the url to retrieve it from, you could use the jQuery .load() method, e.g.

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" )
```

Where #container has the data you want, and #result is where you want to load it to.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: This really helped! Only issue is the page im grabbing information from is an external url - which seems to not be working

Answer (score 0):

You could store the web page as an html string in localStorage. It's not too complex.

```
localStorage.setItem('myPage','<div>Your html page in a string friendly format</div>');
```

to retrieve:

```
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('myPage');
console.log('retrievedObject: ', retrievedObject);
```

Comment: Is that javascript? I'm assuming i just put that inside some script tags and add a matching div for it to be placed into? Sorry I'm not familiar with the script type